# Difference between rand(min, max) and rand()/getrandmax()

Tags: php, random

I saw some people trying to generate random numbers between a range of two numbers using just:

```
$random_num = rand($min, $max);
```

while I see other people using something more complicated like "Dividing rand() by the maximum random number, multiply it by the range and add the starting number:

```
$random_num = $min + ($max - $min) * (rand()/getrandmax());
```

where **$min** is the starting number and **$max** is the ending number.

I would like to know what is the difference between these two ways, is one better than the other, if so why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The former gives you an integer in the range:

```
$min = 1;
$max = 100;
echo rand($min, $max);

25
```

The latter gives you a float in the range:

```
echo $min + ($max - $min) * (rand()/getrandmax());

25.653779622937
```

Other than that, the only difference you need to be concerned with is that `rand()` is not considered sufficient for security purposes. If you need cryptographically strong (i.e., not predictable) random numbers, use `random_int()` or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.